# How to make webpack bundle all CSS and JS resources and dependencies into a single file? Essentially forgo the hot loading aspect of webpack

Tags: webpack

Webpack newbie here...

I have a react project that is using webpack along with babel and a bunch of other dependencies, however, I'd like to bundle all the necessary Javascript into a single file and all the other necessary CSS into another file.

Ideally, I'd want these files so that I can simply just reference them from an existing web app.

Comment: Please go through the new [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org). This one on [splitting CSS](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-css/) might be helpful.